# New instance every time?

Tags: c#

In the following code, which is better? To call add page from within CardPanelDesigner_AddPage? Or use the Func TransactionFunction??

Basically I want to know if doing the inner func will create a "new function" every time :S I don't even know what I'm asking.

Is there an overhead to doing the inner function or should I use the addpage?

```
    private object AddPage(IDesignerHost Host, object Sender)
    {
        return null;
    }

    private void CardPanelDesigner_AddPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IDesignerHost DesignerHost = (IDesignerHost)GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));
        if (DesignerHost != null)
        {
            Func<IDesignerHost, object, object> TransactionFunction = (Host, Param) =>
            {
                return null;
            };

            TransactionInfo("Add Page", DesignerHost, AddPage); //Add page? OR TransactionFunction? :S
        }
    }
```

Comment: CardPanelDesigner_AddPage and the TransactionFunction don't do the same thing. I don't know what you are asking either ;)

Comment: What? You down-voted without even reading it :S

There is an INNER function.. A function within a function by the use of Func<...> and a lambda;

I'm asking if it's better to use the inner function or use the addpage function.

Basically.. Does TransactionFunction act as a variable.. Does it create a new instance of a function every time the outer function is called..

Comment: @levib He's asking whether `TransactionFunction` should be initialised as per within `CardPanelDesigner_AddPage` or should be initialised like so: `Func<IDesignerHost, object, object> TransactionFunction = AddPage;`... I think

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames - I didn't down vote it. I asked a question to try and better understand your question so I could help you out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `TransactionFunction` will create a new object each time `CardPanelDesigner_AddPage` is called. The performance overhead of this however will likely be negligible. You should do whatever reads best to you (and your team).